# Getting the value of a selected drop down list Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, laravel-form

I have tried searching for his and unfortunately I haven't got the solution yet. Hope someone could help me with this. I am trying to get the selected input of this select form:

onewayflight.blade.php

```
{{ Form::label('adult','Adults: ') }} 
           {{ Form::select('adult', ['12+'=>'12+ years',
                                    '1'=>'1','2'=>'2',
                                    '3'=>'3','4'=>'4',
                                    '5'=>'5','6'=>'6',
                                    '7'=>'7','8'=>'8',
                                    '9'=>'9','10'=>'10',
                                    '11'=>'11','12'=>'12',
                                    '13'=>'13','14'=>'14',
                                    '15'=>'15','16'=>'16',
                                    '17'=>'17','18'=>'18',
                                    '19'=>'19','20'=>'20'],'1',array('class'=>'class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"')) }}
```

This is what I've passed on my controllers:

```
$a = Input::get('adult');
    return View::make('content.onewayflightresults')->with('adult',$a);
```

What would I be throwing in for it to be viewed on a blade template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
{{ Form::select('adult', [/* here your array */],$adult,array('class'=>'class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"')) }}
```

because in 3rd parameter you pass value of selected element.

**EDIT**

If you want just display it, you should use

```
{{{ $adult }}}
```

Comment: but I just want to echo out the selected value instead of making a drop down list.

Comment: Tried that one already sir but it would come up with an 'Undefined variable: adult' error

Comment: @staphhelpme It should work. Are you sure you use this view `content.onewayflightresults` only in this part of code? It seems probably not.

Comment: Due to my ignorance and unfamiliarity of this framework, I've made 2 Views, which caused the error. Got it all working now. I've tweaked the code a bit and used the one you suggested. Thanks sir!